# Own WordPress theme with custom AFCs > Export all to theme format?

Tags: themes, advanced-custom-fields

This is just a question to you guys. 
I've made my own WordPress theme where I used a template from some site. 
I've customized the blog posts with the Advanced Custom Fields plugin. 
I have no webdesign degree or great skill.

A colleague asked if I could help him set up a WordPress site with the same theme. And ofcourse I can, but then I started to wonder is there any way I could implement the AFCs settings in the theme itself, or is there a tutorial to do this?

If there is, could someone send me in the right direction?

Comment: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/register-fields-via-php/

Answer (score 0):

In your WordPress backend: Custom fields > Tools > Select all groups > Export file. Then on your colleague's site repeat but change the last step to import file.